# Can you use pivot_root to mount an EBS root onto an EC2 Spot Instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I was looking at the instructions here http://www.ivarch.com/blogs/oss/2007/01/resize-a-live-root-fs-a-howto.shtml

I wonder if these can be modified to remount an EBS volume as the root fs in an EC2 Spot Instance?

Comment: And what are you going to do when your spot instance terminates?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I will re-launch it and re-mount the same EBS volume. The idea here is that after termination the new instance will come up with the original root volume (losing some data, nothing important), but the re-mounted EBS root persists between interruptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed `pivot_root` can be used for this purpose but it has to be done during early initialization (e.g. inside of `/sbin/init`) before other processes have started up creating a dependency on the initial root filesystem.

Here are some scripts that automate the process:
https://github.com/atramos/ec2-spotter